# AngularJS 1.6.8: Unable to pass data from controller to view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-1.6

Not sure where I am going wrong.

Below are the codes for the all the respective files. Its a very basic SPA with routing.

`index.html`

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Bookstore</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="home">Bookstore</a>
            </div>

        </div> 
    </nav> 
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" ui-sref="dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" ui-sref="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" ui-sref="about">About Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
               <ui-view>

               </ui-view>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="about/about.component.js"></script>
    <script src="contact/contact.component.js"></script>
    <script src="dashboard/dashboard.component.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`app.js`

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
app.controller('mainCtrl',function(){

});

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
      })
      .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'dashboard/dashboard.html'
      })
      .state('contact', {
        url: '/contact',
        templateUrl: 'contact/contact.html'
      })
      .state('about', {
        url: '/about',
       // templateUrl: 'about/about.html',
        component: 'aboutComponent'
      })
}]);
```

`about.html`

```
<div ngController="aboutController">
    <div class="heading text-center">
        <h1>About Us</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="text text-center">
        <p>{{$ctrl.information}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

`about.component.js`

```
    angular.module('myApp')
    .component('aboutComponent', {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},    
    templateUrl:'about/about.html',
    controller: aboutController,
    // controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindings:{
      information:'='
    }

  });

  function aboutController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.information = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita fuga quas eaque ipsa praesentium asperiores! Saepe neque nemo consequuntur enim sunt est quos eaque alias quis fugit nihil, provident iusto!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita fuga quas eaque ipsa praesentium asperiores! Saepe neque nemo consequuntur enim sunt est quos eaque alias quis fugit nihil, provident iusto!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita fuga quas eaque ipsa praesentium asperiores! Saepe neque nemo consequuntur enim sunt est quos eaque [![enter image description here][1]][1]alias quis fugit nihil, provident iusto!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita fuga quas eaque ipsa praesentium asperiores! Saepe neque nemo consequuntur enim sunt est quos eaque alias quis fugit nihil, provident iusto!';
  };
```

Comment: Think there's a mistake 
    var vm = this; 
should read 
    var ctrl = this;
and replace instances of vm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use the controllerAs: 'vm' option and then use in the template

```
<div ng-controller="aboutController">
    <div class="heading text-center">
        <h1>About Us</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="text text-center">
        <p>{{vm.information}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

OR

Assign this to ctrl in the component.

```
var ctrl = this;
ctrl.information = 'Lorem ipsum ...';
```

AND

Remove the binding option given that you are not using the component as an element and passing the 'information' in.

Comment: thanks for responding. I had tried that. didn't work.

Comment: You need to uncomment controllerAs: 'vm' for the first option but remove it for the second. Did you try that?

Comment: If you put it in a plunker or codepen I could take a look.

Comment: woo... So, I tried second option. I didn't worked by removing ` controllerAs: 'vm'` for second option. But, It did worked by removing `bindings:{information:'='}` .. No idea why

Comment: When setting bindings it expects the data to be passed as an attribute if an element type of component. However it seems you are setting the component directly on the route. It must take it out of scope somehow. Not really used that method before. I'll update the answer to include your finding.

Comment: There's a typo. It's `ng-controller`, not `ngController`.